# Why does a redirect function outside of flask in a route like /register not redirect if I call the function?

Tags: python, flask

I have 2 functions `check_if_username_not_in_db` and `check_if_email_not_in_db` that are not redirecting in the register route causing an non unique constraint in the db.

I managed to get the code working in the register route if I put the code below,

```
if check_username != None or check_email != None:` 
    `return render_template('register.html',title='register', form=form)`  right
```

after `check_if_username_not_in_db` and `check_if_email_not_in_db`.

I tested the code in pytest and it works so I have no idea why it needs the extra code.
Could someone please explain why?

**flaskapp/app.py**

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

import os 
basedir_for_database = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir_for_database, 'app.db')   
app.config['SQLAlCHEMY_TRACK_mODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'zzzzzzzzzz'

from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


from flask_login import UserMixin


class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)
    hashed_password = db.Column(db.String(128))


# Register forms 
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm 
from wtforms import PasswordField, StringField, SubmitField 
   
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Length 

class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    '''
    This is in /register route.
    The forms are username, email, password and confirm_password
    '''
    
    username = StringField('Username',validators=
    [
    DataRequired(message='Username is required'),
    Length(min=2, max=25 , message='Must be between 2 and 25 characters'),
    ])
 
    email = StringField('Email', validators=
    [
    DataRequired('Email is required'),
    Length(min=4, max=35, message='Must be between 4 and 25 characters'),
    ])
 
 
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=
    [
    DataRequired('Password is required'),
    Length(min=8, max=25, message='Must be between 8 and 25 characters'),
    ])
 
    confirm_password = PasswordField('Repeat Password', validators=
    [
    DataRequired('Does not match password'),
    ])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
 


 


import bcrypt



@app.route("/", methods = ['GET'])
@app.route("/home", methods = ['GET'])
def home():
    return render_template('home.html', title='home')



from flask import flash, redirect, url_for, render_template


def check_if_username_not_in_db(username_form):    
    '''
    if the username is not in the db the code works,
    if not it redirects.
    This runs in the /register route.
    '''
 
    if User.query.filter_by(username=username_form).first():
        flash('The username is already taken. Please select another username for registration.') # okay wording?  
        return redirect(url_for('register'))
    else:
        flash('Success the username is not taken and you can successfully register.')
        return None
 
 
def check_if_email_not_in_db(email_form):    
    '''
    if the email is not in the db the code works,
    if not it redirects.
    This runs in the /register route.
    '''
    if User.query.filter_by(email=email_form).first():
        flash('The email is already taken. Please select another username for registration.') # okay wording?  
        return redirect(url_for('register'))
    else:
        flash('Success the email is not taken and you can successfully register.')
        return None


@app.route("/register", methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def register():
 
    form = RegistrationForm()
    # form.validate_on_submit(): are always the same line of render template to always allow a get request.
    if form.validate_on_submit():
 
        username_form = form.username.data
        email_form = form.email.data
        #plaintext_password_form = form.password.data
        #confirm_plaintext_password_form = form.confirm_password.data
        
        #compare_registration_password_fields(plaintext_password_form, confirm_plaintext_password_form)
        # Don't check passwords for security reasons. 
        
        # check_if_user_already_added
        check_if_username_not_in_db(username_form)    # why not redirects      
        check_if_email_not_in_db(email_form) # why not redirects 
 
 
   
 
 
        # For quicker registration comment while testing
        
        #make_password_contain_capital(plaintext_password_form)
        #make_password_contain_number(plaintext_password_form:
        #make_password_contain_special_characters(plaintext_password_form)
        
        # example password
        plaintext_password = form.password.data
        # converting password to array of bytes
        bytes = plaintext_password.encode('utf-8')
        # generating the salt
        salt = bcrypt.gensalt()
        # Hashing the password
        hashed_password_form = bcrypt.hashpw(bytes, salt)
        # Use this code if adding code to the database the first time.
        add_user = User(username=username_form, email=email_form, hashed_password=hashed_password_form)
        db.session.add(add_user)
        db.session.commit()
        
 
        # db_user = User.query.filter_by(email=email_form).first()
        flash('You have almost registered successfully. Please click the link in your email to complete the registeration.')     
        # This is in the code in a different blueprint or in this example a different part in        the file   
        # send_account_registration_email(db_user)  
        
        
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    return render_template('register.html',title='register', form=form)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**flaskapp/templates/register.html**

```
{%extends "layout.html"%}
<!--get the error message from wtf forms -->
{% from "_formhelpers.html" import render_field %}
 
{% block title %} {{title}} {% endblock title %}
{%block content%}
    <!-- Once you get the error message from ( "_formhelpers.html" import render_field) , you use novalidate to
     get the error message from wtf forms and makes it show up on the screen. %}
    validate makes sure you have the correct route most of the time you can just leave it blank.
    -->
    <form validate ="" id="register" method="POST">
        <!-- Make the secret key work -->
        {{ form.csrf_token }}
        <!--the "render_field" puts -->
        {{ render_field(form.username) }}
        {{ render_field(form.email) }}
        {{ render_field(form.password) }}
        {{ render_field(form.confirm_password) }}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    
 
    <!--make flash message work-->
    {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
        {% if messages %}
            <ul class=flashes>
            {% for message in messages %}
                <p1>  {{message}} </p1>
            {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}
    {% endwith %}    
 
{%endblock content%}
```

**flaskapp/templates/layout.html**

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    {% if title %}
<title> flashblog {{+ title}} </title>
    <!-- The title will say home -->
    {% else %}
           {{ 'home' }}
    {% endif %}
</head>
<body>
 
  
    {% block content %}
 
    {% endblock content %}

</body>
</html>
```

**flaskapp/templates/home.html**

```
{%extends "layout.html"%}

    

{% block content %}  
   
    {% block title %} {{title}} {% endblock title %}

    <h1> Home page <h1/>


{% endblock content %}
```

**flaskapp/templates/_formhelpers.html**

```
{% macro render_field(field) %}
    <dt>{{ field.label }}
    <dd>{{ field(**kwargs)|safe }}
    {% if field.errors %}
        <ul class=errors>
        {% for error in field.errors %}
            <li>{{ error }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endif %}
    </dd>
{% endmacro %}
```

Comment: Your functions for testing whether the username or email already exist return either redirect or none as the return value. Since you do not use this return value in your endpoint and return it to the client using return, the redirect will not be executed either.

Comment: @Detlef
Why does it not redirect right away? If I didn't use a function it would redirect right away. Or am I wrong? Sorry for the edits.

Comment: When a defined function is called, a value is returned and can be used as a result of the call. When you visit the route, your end point will be executed. The return value of this function corresponds to the result that the client receives. A redirect corresponds to an HTTP status and a location header containing the URL. The browser then calls up the URL mentioned. If you call another function within your endpoint that may return a redirect, you have to check whether this is the case and if so, then return it again. The client only responds to the return value of the outermost function.

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question but why is the outer function only called  I think you tried to explain. I am just not getting why.

Comment: In your example, both the outer and inner functions are called. The outer function is called based on the URL mapping. You call the inner function yourself with `check_if_*_not_in_db(*_form)`. However, in Python, indentation limits the scope of variables. A return statement is a way to pass a value between the scopes. When you make a nested function call, you can only pass the return value to the enclosing scope, but not beyond it. If you want to return the value even further, another 'return' statement is necessary to reach the next scope. This is missing for you to carry out the forwarding.

Comment: @Detlef 

Is it possible to show an example of this using pure python and not python flask? Or can this  only be shown because of flask?

Comment: The problem is not limited to Flask, you will also encounter it in pure Python. Nevertheless, I used your example as a basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So that your return value from the function to validate the user name is not lost, the result of the function must be checked again for None and otherwise returned again. Only then will the value be returned by the register function and reach the client.

```py
# This function returns either a redirect or None, 
# depending on whether the username exists.
def check_if_username_not_in_db(username_form):    
    # Start of the local scope of the function.
    
    if User.query.filter_by(username=username_form).first():
        flash('The username is already taken. Please select another username for registration.') 
        
        # A return statement ends the local scope and 
        # passes a value to the calling scope.
        return redirect(url_for('register'))
    else:
        flash('Success the username is not taken and you can successfully register.')
        return None
    
    # Final end of the local scope of the function.

@app.route('/register', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    # Start of the local scope of the function.
    
    form = RegistrationForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        
        # Calling the function to check the username.
        # In order to execute the redirect, the return value 
        # must be returned again if it is not None.
        # Otherwise the return value ends up being nothing.
        # 
        # The scope of the return value of the nested function call is 
        # limited here by the local scope of the function.

        result = check_if_username_not_in_db(form.username.data)
        if result is not None: 
            return result

        # ...

    return render_template('register.html', ...)
```

As the example shows, outsourcing the validation of the user name and the email is not optimal due to the double check.

The following example shows you an optimized version in which the uniqueness of the user name and email is checked within the form. This has the additional advantage that the feedback to the user is displayed as part of the form field.

```py
'''
Install dependencies:
% pip install flask flask_bcrypt flask_login flask_sqlalchemy flask_wtf email_validator

Create the database:
% flask --app app.py shell 
>> from app import db, User
>> db.create_all()

Start the application:
% flask --app app.py --debug run 
'''

from flask import (
    Flask, 
    flash, 
    redirect, 
    render_template, 
    request, 
    url_for
)
# Here flask-bcrypt is used instead of bcrypt directly.
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt 
from flask_login import UserMixin
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm 
from wtforms import EmailField, PasswordField, StringField, SubmitField 
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Email, EqualTo, Length, ValidationError


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_mapping(
    SECRET_KEY='your secret here',
    # Use the instance folder as the storage location for the database.
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI='sqlite:///app.db', 
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS=False
)
# Initializing flask-bcrypt.
bcrypt = Bcrypt(app) 
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))

    # Getter for the password.
    @property
    def password(self):
        raise AttributeError('writeonly attr: password')

    # Setter for the password.
    @password.setter
    def password(self, value):
        self.password_hash = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(value)

    # Password verification.
    def verify_password(self, value):
        return bcrypt.check_password_hash(self.password_hash, value)


class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    email = EmailField('Email', 
        validators=[
            DataRequired(),
            Length(min=4, max=35),
            Email()
        ]
    )

    username = StringField('Username',
        validators=[
            DataRequired(),
            Length(min=2, max=25),
        ]
    )
 
    password = PasswordField('Password', 
        validators=[
            DataRequired(),
            Length(min=8, max=25),
            EqualTo('password_confirm')
        ]
    )
 
    password_confirm = PasswordField('Repeat Password', 
        validators=[
            DataRequired(),
        ]
    )
    
    submit = SubmitField('Register')
    
    # Validation of the uniqueness of the email.
    def validate_email(self, field):
        if User.query.filter_by(email=field.data).first():
            raise ValidationError('The email is already taken.')

    # Validation of username uniqueness.
    def validate_username(self, field):
        if User.query.filter_by(username=field.data).first():
            raise ValidationError('The username is already taken.')


@app.route('/')
@app.route('/home')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    # Retain inputs if inputs are incorrect.
    form = RegistrationForm(request.form) 
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User()
        # Transfer the form data to the user object.
        form.populate_obj(user) 
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('You have registered successfully.')
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    # Pass all local variables to the template.
    return render_template('register.html', **locals())

# ...
```